# Block producer until consumer is finished (reverse BlockingCollection)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I want a multiple-producer-single-consumer pattern where the *producer* waits until the consumer is finished.

*So why not just call the consumer method?*

Because it's a multi threaded environment and I need the consumer to process items one by one. I would like to avoid putting locks manually (because of the possible pitfalls there) and use something like the wonderful [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).Take() method which blocks the consumer until more items are produced, but I need it also in reverse:

**The consumer should wait for produce, and the producer should wait for the consumer to be finished.**

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Items need to be processed one by one. But they come from requests to a web service and might be concurrent. So I have all service requests send the items to one consumer. But the requests should not send responses until an item has been processed because the web app might be recycled before an item is processed (and the response is saying "item has been processed"). But when a request has not responded yet, Asp.net tries not to recycle the app (AFAIK).

Comment: Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @paparazzo I'm trying to make sense of your comment :) . Items need to be processed one by one. But they come from requests to a web service and might be concurrent. So I have all service requests send the items to one consumer. But the requests should not send responses until an item has been processed because the web app might be recycled before an item is processed. But when a request has not responded yet, Asp.net tries not to recycle the app. (AFAIK) Better?

Comment: I am still confused.  Hopefully you will find someone that can make sense of this.

Comment: @paparazzo No problem. Thanks for trying. It seems like what you mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30943252/939213) can actually work well (I didn't try it yet) - send the item along with a `ManualResetEventSlim` (as mentioned in the comment there) and then `manualResetEventSlim.Wait();` in the producer right after Adding to the BlockingCollection. And when the consumer finishes processing an item, it then calls `manualResetEventSlim.Set();`.

Comment: You can use two collections - one for requests and another for responses. Just mark request with some kind of guid and await it in response collection.

Comment: This is concept also called RPC.

Comment: @eocron Thanks. I'm not sure there's a way to wait for a specific item with BlockingCollection, but I can create a new BlockingCollection for every request and just wait for the response. This is similar to what I've outlined in my comment to paparazzo. Thanks.

Comment: i had same situation in asp.net and i solved it with a singleton that it was thread-safe by itself(used 'lock') so it reduce pitfall. if you think it will help you i can explain how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem requires a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) that can be configured with zero [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.boundedcapacity), so that the producers are blocked until a consumer is ready to accept an item. The minimum `BoundedCapacity` of the built-in `BlockingCollection<T>` is 1, so most likely you'll have to write a custom implementation from scratch. Below is such an implementation, offering the core functionality of a `BlockingCollection<T>`. Only the methods `Add`, `CompleteAdding` and `GetConsumingEnumerable` are implemented. Features like cancellation and timeout are not supported:

```
public class ZeroCapacityBlockingCollection<T>
{
    private class Entry : TaskCompletionSource<(bool HasValue, T Value)>
    {
        public Entry() : base(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously) { }
        public T Item { get; init; }
    }

    private readonly object _locker = new object();
    private readonly Queue<Entry> _producers = new();
    private readonly Queue<Entry> _consumers = new();
    private bool _completed = false;

    public bool IsCompleted => Volatile.Read(ref _completed);

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Entry entry;
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (_completed) throw new InvalidOperationException();
                if (_consumers.TryDequeue(out entry)) goto completeConsumer;
                entry = new Entry() { Item = item };
                _producers.Enqueue(entry);
            }
            // Wait for a consumer to accept this entry
            var (accepted, _) = entry.Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (accepted) return;
            continue;
        completeConsumer:
            // Offer the item to an already waiting consumer
            if (entry.TrySetResult((true, item))) return;
        }
    }

    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_completed) return;
            _completed = true;
            while (_producers.TryDequeue(out var entry))
                entry.TrySetException(new InvalidOperationException());
            while (_consumers.TryDequeue(out var entry))
                entry.TrySetResult((false, default));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetConsumingEnumerable()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Entry entry;
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (_completed) yield break;
                if (_producers.TryDequeue(out entry)) goto completeProducer;
                entry = new Entry();
                _consumers.Enqueue(entry);
            }
            // Wait for a producer to offer an item through this entry
            var (hasValue, value) = entry.Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (hasValue) yield return value;
            continue;
        completeProducer:
            // Accept the item offered by an already waiting producer
            if (entry.TrySetResult((true, default))) yield return entry.Item;
        }
    }
}
```