# Is it possible to replace yield by await?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, yield

Both yield and await are capable of interrupting the execution of a method. Both of them can be used to let the caller continue execution. Only the await seems to me to be a stronger tool that can do not only this but much more. Is it true?

I would like to replace the following:

```cs
yield item;
```

By this:

```cs
await buffer.SendAsync(item);
```

Is it possible? One thing I like about yield is that everything happens on one thread. Could it be the same with the await approach?

I tried to implement it as follows:

```cs
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await ConsumeAsync();
    }

    // instead of IEnumerable<int> Produce()
    static async Task ProduceAsync(Buffer<int> buffer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Produced {i} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await buffer.SendAsync(i); // instead of yield i;
        }
    }

    static async Task ConsumeAsync()
    {
        Buffer<int> buffer = new Buffer<int>(ProduceAsync); // instead enumerable.GetEnumerator
        while (true)
        {
            int i = await buffer.ProduceAsync(); // instead of enumerator.MoveNext(); enumerator.Current
            Console.WriteLine($"Consumed {i} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}

class Buffer<T>
{
    private T item;
    public Buffer(Func<Buffer<T>, Task> producer)
    {
        producer(this); // starts the producer
    }
    public async Task<T> ProduceAsync()
    {
        // block the consumer
        // continue the execution of producer
        // await until producer produces something
        return item;
    }
    public async Task SendAsync(T item)
    {
        this.item = item;
        // block the producer
        // continue the execution of consumer
        // await until the consumer is requesting next item
    }
}
```

But I did not know how to do the synchronization to keep everything on one thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use patterns like that. I have done so when writing state machines for UI interactions, where the user needs to place a sequence of clicks, and different things should happen between each click. Using something like `await mouse.GetDownTask()` allow the code to be written in a fairly linear way.

But that does not necessarily mean that that it was easy to read or understand. The underlying mechanisms to make it all work where quite horrible. So you should be aware that this is abuse of the system, and that other readers of your code will probably not expect such a usage. So use with care, and make sure you are on top of your documentation.

To make this work you likely need to use [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-7.0). Something like this *might* work:

```
class Buffer<T>
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new ();
    public Buffer() { }
    public Task<T> Receive() => tcs.Task;

    public void Send(T item)
    {
        tcs.SetResult(item);
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    }
}
```

You should also be aware of deadlocks. This is a potential problem when using fake async on a single thread like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1):

```
class Buffer<T>
{
    private readonly Channel<T> _channel = Channel.CreateBounded<T>(1);

    public Task<T> ProduceAsync()
    {
        // block the consumer
        // continue the execution of producer
        // await until producer produces something
        return _channel.Reader.ReadAsync().AsTask();
    }

    public Task SendAsync(T item)
    {
        return _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(item).AsTask();
        // block the producer
        // continue the execution of consumer
        // await until the consumer is requesting next item
    }
}
```

The built-in `Channel<T>` implementations have a minimum bounded capacity of 1. My understanding is that you want a channel with zero capacity, like the channels in [Go language](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2). Implementing one is doable, but not trivial. For a starting point, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726822/block-producer-until-consumer-is-finished-reverse-blockingcollection/71811712#71811712).